# ASP. NET ViewState and Browser back button

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, viewstate

I'm having viewstate issues when going from page A to page B and (using browser's back button) once again to page A. When I click the control that made me go to page B the first time it gives me an "invalid viewstate" error.

I'm using Devexpress ASPxScheduler and the action to go from A to B is double clicking an appointment.

The problem is that when I click browser's back button then viewstate stored is page B viewstate and I'm in page A.

So...I can't be the only one in this situation.
If you gone through situations like this, please share

Answer (score 0):

Viewstate is on a page by page basis. When page b is loaded page a's viewstate is no more. Use a session (stored on the server) and use that in page a if the back button is pushed.

Otherwise a cookie, but imho session is best here.

Comment: The only problem is that Page.ViewState is readOnly.
But I'll try to figure out a way to do it.
Thanks :)